# Separating MediaPlayers Volume

Tags: android, seekbar, android-audiomanager

I can't separate the volume on each MediaPlayer. All I need to do is mp1 should have its own volume control as well as mp2. The codes are shown below. I even tried to create a setVolume() on each MediaPlayer but no luck!

Both seekBar1 and seekBar2 volumes works on both mp1 and mp2. I just need to separate them having seekBar1 should only be works for mp1 .

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
MediaPlayer mp1;
MediaPlayer mp2;


AudioManager audioManager1;
AudioManager audioManager2;

     ...


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);


    audioManager1 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager2 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    int maxVolume1 = audioManager1.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume1 = audioManager1.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


    int maxVolume2 = audioManager2.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume2 = audioManager2.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    SeekBar volumeControl1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    SeekBar volumeControl2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

    volumeControl1.setMax(maxVolume1);
    volumeControl2.setMax(maxVolume2);

    volumeControl1.setProgress(curVolume1);
    volumeControl2.setProgress(curVolume2);


    volumeControl1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {



            audioManager1.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);

        }

    });
```